# $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$: What units are used to measure $E$, $m$, $c$ and $p$?

Tags: energy, units, si-units

\begin{equation}
    E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2
\end{equation}

If I am using this equation to figure out the energy of something, what units would I use? Would it be the metric system? I.e. kilograms for $m$, meters per second for $p$, kilometers per second for $c$? And what units of measurement are used for $E$?

Comment: Use the SI units. Joules for E.

Comment: *"meters per second for p"* Er...no. Kg m / s in SI, and likewise the velocity there should be in m/s so that you don't have to mess around with loose factors of $10^3$. Of course particle physicists would use $c=1$ units and measure energy, mass and momentum all in GeV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any consistent system will do. That's the entire point of systems of units--if you stick to one, you don't need to worry about the units too much. And it never happens that a certain equation only works in a certain system*.

In this case, you would use joules ($\:\mathrm{J}\equiv\:\mathrm{kg\:m^2\:s^{-2}}$), the metric unit of energy. If you were using the cgs system, $m$ would be in grams, $p$ would be in $\:\mathrm{g\:cm\:s^{-1}}$, $c$ would be in centimetres per second, and $E$ would be in ergs ($\:\mathrm{erg}\cong\:\mathrm{g\:cm^2\:s^{-2}}$),

<sup>Physical constants may change. Also, some equations have some constants set to one (eg Planck units, Gaussian units), so they may disappear entirely. For example, if $c=1$ (Planck units), the equation becomes $E^2=m^2+p^2$.</sup>

Comment: keep in mind that constants of value $1$ are omitted, thus it is not necessarily true that all equations are equally valid in all unit systems - examples are Lorentz–Heaviside vs Gaussian vs SI units of elecromagnetism as well as various systems of natural units

Comment: @Christoph: True... I'll add that.

Comment: Why are you saying that 1 J is only *approximately* equal to 1 kg m$^{2}$ s$^{-2}$?

Comment: @user16307: No, $\cong$ and $\equiv$ mean "congruent to" or "equivalent".  $\sim$ and $\simeq$ are "similar to".

Comment: @user16307 The symbol for approximately equal to (when you are being painfully precise) is $\approx$. To get it in LaTeX you use `\approx`

Comment: @dmckee: Btw, is there any difference between `\cong` and `\equiv`?

Comment: I've no idea. A mathematician might makes a fine distinction, but I'm not clear. I use `\equiv` from habit.

Comment: @dmckee: Ah. I'll ask Math Chat then. I use `\equiv` on paper but `\cong` in LaTeX because I read the symbol as "is congruent to" and naturally think of `\cong`. Confusing :S

Comment: by (some) convention, $\equiv$ is used for equal by definition and $\cong$ for isomorphic (ie structurally equivalent but not necessarily equal); in your case, $\equiv$ would probably be more appropriate

Comment: @Chris Yeah, the folks at Math SE said something similar. Fixed, thanks :)